# how to integrate essl biometric device data to attendence system through php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the punch in and out time from biometric device and store it in another attendence product database (mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the SDK from zkteco site. and go through the sdk sample programs and documents.

If you are already familiar with the zk program then, You have to read all the users from one device (using ReadAllUserID to buffer the data into device's memory and then GetAllUserInfo) then call SetUserInfo for every user id with another device.

If you are like to do it over http please check http://zkteco.tech/application/biometric-web-api.html for api details.

Comment: > http://zkteco.tech/application/biometric-web-api.html for api details.< link does not work anymore, please update your answer